# How do i compare means between two samples with binary dependent variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

I have one group of firms with restatements. One control group with no restatements. The dependent variable is binary, 1 for restatement and 0 for no restatement. I have performed a logistic regression. But I also have to compare the means between the two samples (restatement group and control group which consists of no restatements). 
Which test do i use to compare the means? I have used the anova test but i think that is not right, since the assumptions do not work for binary outcome variables.

Comment: Anova often works for binary data because of the central limit theorem .